# C++ How to use regular expressions and iterate over string with non-latin text?

Tags: c++, utf-8, stl, utf-16, utf

I am working on an application that encodes information with different ciphers, for example, Atbash, Scytale, Caesar, etc. I decided to divide it into two parts: GUI with Qt and a separate library with all encoding functions, which could be later used in other projects. The first cipher - Atbash - requires regular expressions and iterating over code points (letters) of an input message. Regular std::string and std::regex don't seem to work with multi-byte UTF-8 code points, so I came up with several different solutions:

1. Use `std::string` and `std::regex` with an one-byte encoding for my language, for example, CP1251 or CP866. It would be complicated to convert such `std::string` to `QString`, which uses UTF-16.
2. Use `QString` and `QRegExp`. Works seamlessly with my particular application, but it will be difficult to use this library outside of Qt later.
3. Use `wchar_t`, `std::wstring` and `std::wregex`. I have read that `wstring` is not cross-platform.
4. Use `std::u32string` with `u32regex` from Boost.

Which option should I use?

Code example:

```
std::wstring atbash::encode(const std::wstring& message) {
    if (!std::regex_match(message, std::wregex(L"^[а-яёА-ЯЁa-zA-Z .,]+$"))) {
        throw "A message can contain only cyrillic and latin letters, spaces, dots and commas.";
    }

    auto result = std::wstring();
    for (auto symbol : message) {
        if (std::regex_match(std::wstring(1, symbol), std::wregex(L"[ .,ёЁ]"))) {
            result += symbol;
        } else if (std::regex_match(std::wstring(1, symbol), std::wregex(L"[а-я]"))) {
            result += L'а' + L'я' - symbol;
        } else if (std::regex_match(std::wstring(1, symbol), std::wregex(L"[А-Я]"))) {
            result += L'А' + L'Я' - symbol;
        } else if (std::regex_match(std::wstring(1, symbol), std::wregex(L"[a-z]"))) {
            result += L'a' + L'z' - symbol;
        } else if (std::regex_match(std::wstring(1, symbol), std::wregex(L"[A-Z]"))) {
            result += L'A' + L'Z' - symbol;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think `std::wstring` should be cross-platform but on some platforms it will hold `UTF-16` and on others `UTF-32`. But you should still be able to write generic code with it.

Comment: You might want to check how all those options behave when presented with chars that do not fit within a single code unit.

Comment: Using `wstring`/`u32string` is just a transition from utf-8 to either utf-16 or utf-32. `wstring` may give a false sense of correctness (because it may use utf-16 with surrogate pairs), so I would not use it. There is no "right" decision here, but I'd probably go with `u32string` to work on code points, not code units of utf-16.

Comment: @spectras the first one (CP1251) doesn't have multi-byte characters at all, 2 and 3 will probably work only with 8 and 16 bit code points, but my cyrillic letters all take 16 bits. I have not ever used Boost, so I didn't test the 4th option.

Comment: Hi, Can you eventually provide a minimal code with a main to allow easy reproduction as well as some examples of test cases please?